# Adding total of a row and a col given certain conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query :

```
select pivot_table.*
from   (
  Select STATUS,USER_TYPE
  FROM   TRANSACTIONS tr 
         join TRANSACTION_STATUS_CODES sc on sc.id = tr.user_type
         join TRANSACTION_USER_TYPES ut on ut.id=tr.user_type 
  WHERE  Tr.User_Type between 1 and 5
  And    tr.status!=1
  AND    Tr.Update_Date BETWEEN TO_DATE('2022-01-01 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS')
                        AND     TO_DATE('2022-11-13 23:59:59', 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS')
) t
pivot(
  count(user_type)
  FOR user_type IN (1,2,3,5) 
)  pivot_table;
```

Which gives:

| status | 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 13 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 8 |

Wanted result:

| status | 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 |
| 4 | 13 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 13 |
| 5 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 6 |
| 0 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 8 | 12 |
| sum of statuses 2,4,5 | 17 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 17 |
| sum of all statuses | 26 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 35 |

I have tried adding:

```sql
Select STATUS,USER_TYPE,
       count(user_type) as records,
       sum(user_type) over (partition by status) as total
```

and in the end:

```sql
pivot ( sum (records) for user_type in (1,2,3,5)) pivot_table
```

but logically I am still not there.

Comment: Looks like you want to use a `ROLLUP` with filters on grouping sets and then conditional aggregation, rather than `PIVOT`, to get the totals.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `GROUP BY CUBE` with conditional aggregation and filters on the grouping sets:

```sql
SELECT CASE GROUPING_ID(status, CASE WHEN status IN (2, 4, 5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
       WHEN 0
       THEN TO_CHAR(status)
       WHEN 2
       THEN 'SUB-TOTAL'
       ELSE 'TOTAL'
       END AS status,
       COUNT(CASE user_type WHEN 1 THEN 1 END) AS "1",
       COUNT(CASE user_type WHEN 2 THEN 1 END) AS "2",
       COUNT(CASE user_type WHEN 3 THEN 1 END) AS "3",
       COUNT(CASE user_type WHEN 5 THEN 1 END) AS "5",
       COUNT(*) AS total
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY CUBE(status, CASE WHEN status IN (2, 4, 5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
HAVING GROUPING_ID(status, CASE WHEN status IN (2, 4, 5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) IN (0, 3)
OR     (   GROUPING_ID(status, CASE WHEN status IN (2, 4, 5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 2
       AND CASE WHEN status IN (2, 4, 5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1 )
```

Which, for the sample data (representing the output of your many joined tables):

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (status, user_type) AS
  SELECT 2, 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 13 UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 5 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 0, 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 0, 5 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  8;
```

Outputs:

| STATUS | 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 8 | 12 |
| 3 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 6 |
| 2 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 |
| 4 | 13 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 13 |
| 5 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| SUB-TOTAL | 17 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 17 |
| TOTAL | 26 | 0 | 0 | 9 | 35 |

You can change the string literals to match the row titles for your desired output.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/l2qU-ZV-)

Comment: working fantastic, one thing is that Im trying to understand why status was casted to char, because I need to build this query in a string builder and those lines :  COUNT(CASE user_type WHEN 1 THEN 1 END) AS "1" prevent me from doing so because of the parentheses.

Comment: @גלמור In a `CASE` expression, all the outputs need to be the same data type and you are outputting strings for the total and sub-total rows so you need to convert the status from a number to a string as well, which requires `TO_CHAR`. As for the quoted identifiers, either escape the double quotes when you use `StringBuilder` or use an identifier that does not require quoting [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qTGaIrXk).

Comment: appreciated much, cheers mate have a good weekend

Answer (score 0):

One of the options to do it is to use MODEL clause like this:

```sql
Select 
    *
From
    (
        Select Cast(p.STATUS as VARCHAR2(30)) "STATUS",  p."1", p."2", p."3", p."5"
        From pivot_table p Union All
        Select 'Sum of Statuses 2, 4, 5', Null, Null, Null, Null From Dual Union All
        Select 'Sum of All Statuses', Null, Null, Null, Null From Dual
    ) 
MODEL
    Dimension By      (STATUS)
    Measures          ("1", "2", "3", "5", 0 "TOTAL")
    Rules     
          (
              "1"['Sum of All Statuses'] = Sum("1")[ANY],     -- Grand Total of Column 1 = Sum(1) for ANY Status (Dimension)
              "2"['Sum of All Statuses'] = Sum("2")[ANY],
              "3"['Sum of All Statuses'] = Sum("3")[ANY],
              "5"['Sum of All Statuses'] = Sum("5")[ANY],
              --
              "1"['Sum of Statuses 2, 4, 5'] = Sum("1")[STATUS IN('2', '4', '5')],    -- SubTotal of Column 1 = Sum(1) for Status IN 2, 4, 5
              "2"['Sum of Statuses 2, 4, 5'] = Sum("2")[STATUS IN('2', '4', '5')],
              "3"['Sum of Statuses 2, 4, 5'] = Sum("3")[STATUS IN('2', '4', '5')],
              "5"['Sum of Statuses 2, 4, 5'] = Sum("5")[STATUS IN('2', '4', '5')],
              --
              TOTAL[ANY] = "1"[CV()] + "2"[CV()] + "3"[CV()] + "5"[CV()]      -- for each row do the addition of columns with the same Current Value 'CV()' of Status
          )
```

With the data from your question:

```sql
WITH
    pivot_table AS
        (   
       Select 2 "STATUS", 3 "1", 0 "2", 0 "3", 0 "5" From Dual Union All
       Select 4 "STATUS", 13 "1", 0 "2", 0 "3", 0 "5" From Dual Union All
       Select 5 "STATUS", 1 "1", 0 "2", 0 "3", 0 "5" From Dual Union All
       Select 3 "STATUS", 5 "1", 0 "2", 0 "3", 1 "5" From Dual Union All
       Select 0 "STATUS", 4 "1", 0 "2", 0 "3", 8 "5" From Dual 
        )
```

The result should be:

| STATUS | 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 |
| 4 | 13 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 13 |
| 5 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 6 |
| 0 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 8 | 12 |
| Sum of Statuses 2, 4, 5 | 17 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 17 |
| Sum of All Statuses | 26 | 0 | 0 | 9 | 35 |

Regards...