# how to get some kind of value inside parantheses - sql query related

Tags: java, oracle

I have the following query which works great in my oracle developer:

```
        sb.Append("SELECT CASE GROUPING_ID(status, CASE WHEN status IN(2, 4, 5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ");
        sb.Append(" WHEN 0 THEN TO_CHAR(status) WHEN 2 THEN 'SUB-TOTAL' ELSE 'TOTAL' END AS status, ");
1       sb.Append(" COUNT(CASE user_type WHEN 1 THEN 1 END) AS "1" ");
2       sb.Append(" COUNT(CASE user_type WHEN 2 THEN 1 END) AS "2", ");
3       sb.Append(" COUNT(CASE user_type WHEN 3 THEN 1 END) AS "4", ");
4       sb.Append(" COUNT(CASE user_type WHEN 5 THEN 1 END) AS "5", ");
        sb.Append(" COUNT(*) AS total ");
        sb.Append(" FROM(Select STATUS, USER_TYPE FROM TRANSACTIONS tr  join TRANSACTION_STATUS_CODES sc on sc.id = tr.user_type join ");
        sb.Append(" TRANSACTION_USER_TYPES ut on ut.id = tr.user_type ");
        sb.Append(" WHERE Tr.User_Type between 1 and 5 And tr.status != 1 AND Tr.Update_Date BETWEEN     TO_DATE('2022-01-01 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS')     AND TO_DATE('2022-11-13 23:59:59', 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS')) ");
        sb.Append(" GROUP BY CUBE(status, CASE WHEN status IN(2, 4, 5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ");
        sb.Append(" HAVING GROUPING_ID(status, CASE WHEN status IN (2, 4, 5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) IN(0, 3) ");
        sb.Append(" OR(GROUPING_ID(status, CASE WHEN status IN(2, 4, 5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 2 ");
        sb.Append("   AND CASE WHEN status IN(2, 4, 5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1) " );
```

In the lines I marked from 1->4 I have an error because I cant use parantheses inside parantheses.
what I want is to be able to actually put "1" , "2" inside my stringbuilder, how can I do that??

thanks

Comment: You are missing a `,` at the end of the string literal of the line marked `1`.

Answer (score 0):

[As mentioned in comments on the answer to the previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74447208/adding-total-of-a-row-and-a-col-given-certain-conditions#comment131439217_74447863), escape the double quotes inside the string literal.

```java
sb.Append(" COUNT(CASE user_type WHEN 1 THEN 1 END) AS \"1\", ");
sb.Append(" COUNT(CASE user_type WHEN 2 THEN 1 END) AS \"2\", ");
sb.Append(" COUNT(CASE user_type WHEN 3 THEN 1 END) AS \"4\", ");
sb.Append(" COUNT(CASE user_type WHEN 5 THEN 1 END) AS \"5\", ");
```

or use a non-quoted identifier:

```java
sb.Append(" COUNT(CASE user_type WHEN 1 THEN 1 END) AS type1, ");
sb.Append(" COUNT(CASE user_type WHEN 2 THEN 1 END) AS type2, ");
sb.Append(" COUNT(CASE user_type WHEN 3 THEN 1 END) AS type4, ");
sb.Append(" COUNT(CASE user_type WHEN 5 THEN 1 END) AS type5, ");
```