# Making changes on a pivot table

Tags: oracle

I have the following query:

```
SELECT CASE GROUPING_ID(status, CASE WHEN status IN (2, 4, 5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
       WHEN 0
       THEN TO_CHAR(status)
       WHEN 2
       THEN 'subtotal'
       ELSE 'total'
       END AS status,
       COUNT(CASE user_type WHEN 1 THEN 1 END) AS "1",
       COUNT(CASE user_type WHEN 2 THEN 1 END) AS "2",
       COUNT(CASE user_type WHEN 3 THEN 1 END) AS "3",
       COUNT(CASE user_type WHEN 5 THEN 1 END) AS "5",
       COUNT(*) AS total
FROM   (Select STATUS,USER_TYPE
FROM TRANSACTIONS tr  join TRANSACTION_STATUS_CODES sc on sc.id = tr.user_type join
TRANSACTION_USER_TYPES ut on ut.id=tr.user_type  
WHERE tr.status!=1 AND Tr.Update_Date BETWEEN     TO_DATE('2022-01-01 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS')     AND TO_DATE('2022-11-13 23:59:59', 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS'))
GROUP BY CUBE(status,CASE WHEN status IN (2, 4, 5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
HAVING GROUPING_ID(status, CASE WHEN status IN (2, 4, 5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) IN (0, 3)
OR     (   GROUPING_ID(status, CASE WHEN status IN (2, 4, 5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 2
       AND CASE WHEN status IN (2, 4, 5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1 );
```

which displays:

[[image: table]

with inner query giving ( thats 10 out of 36rows):

[image: inner]

anyways.. I've been asked to change the inner query to a better organized one, so I came up with the following pivot table ( which I want it to be my new inner query ):

```
SELECT p.*
FROM   (
  SELECT user_type,
         status 
  FROM   transactions
  WHERE  status !=1
  AND    Update_Date >= DATE '2022-01-01'
  AND    Update_Date <  DATE '2022-11-14' 
) PIVOT (
  COUNT(*)
  FOR user_type IN (1,2,3,5)
) p
ORDER BY status asc;
```

which gives:

[image]

what I need to try and achieve is the sum of subtotal/total of rows aswell as total of column( as I have in the first table ), and when I try to make it an inner query the outer query doesnt recognize anything..

**so basically to add these:**

[image]

[image]

is that achievable without changing the entire query?
or else, what is the best approach to achieve that?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CUBE` does what you want in a single query and was covered in [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74447863/1509264).

You cannot use `PIVOT` to do what you want in a single query; instead you would need to use multiple queries joined together with `UNION ALL` to calculate the status, sub-total and total parts (which is likely to be much less efficient):

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(status) AS status,
       "1",
       "2",
       "3",
       "5",
       "1" + "2" + "3" + "5" AS total
FROM   table_name
PIVOT ( COUNT(*) FOR user_type IN (1,2,3,5) )
UNION ALL
SELECT 'SUB_TOTAL',
       "1",
       "2",
       "3",
       "5",
       "1" + "2" + "3" + "5" AS total
FROM   (SELECT user_type FROM table_name WHERE status IN (2,4,5))
PIVOT ( COUNT(*) FOR user_type IN (1,2,3,5) )
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TOTAL',
       "1",
       "2",
       "3",
       "5",
       "1" + "2" + "3" + "5" AS total
FROM   (SELECT user_type FROM table_name)
PIVOT ( COUNT(*) FOR user_type IN (1,2,3,5) )
```

or:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(status) AS status,
       COUNT(CASE user_type WHEN 1 THEN 1 END) AS "1",
       COUNT(CASE user_type WHEN 2 THEN 1 END) AS "2",
       COUNT(CASE user_type WHEN 3 THEN 1 END) AS "3",
       COUNT(CASE user_type WHEN 5 THEN 1 END) AS "5",
       COUNT(*) AS total
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY status
UNION ALL
SELECT 'SUB_TOTAL',
       COUNT(CASE user_type WHEN 1 THEN 1 END) AS "1",
       COUNT(CASE user_type WHEN 2 THEN 1 END) AS "2",
       COUNT(CASE user_type WHEN 3 THEN 1 END) AS "3",
       COUNT(CASE user_type WHEN 5 THEN 1 END) AS "5",
       COUNT(*) AS total
FROM   table_name
WHERE  status IN (2,4,5)
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TOTAL',
       COUNT(CASE user_type WHEN 1 THEN 1 END) AS "1",
       COUNT(CASE user_type WHEN 2 THEN 1 END) AS "2",
       COUNT(CASE user_type WHEN 3 THEN 1 END) AS "3",
       COUNT(CASE user_type WHEN 5 THEN 1 END) AS "5",
       COUNT(*) AS total
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data, (also from [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74447863/1509264)):

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (status, user_type) AS
  SELECT 2, 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 13 UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 5 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 0, 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 0, 5 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  8;
```

Both output the same as using a single query with `CUBE`:

| STATUS | 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 |
| 4 | 13 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 13 |
| 0 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 8 | 12 |
| 5 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 6 |
| SUB_TOTAL | 17 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 17 |
| TOTAL | 26 | 0 | 0 | 9 | 35 |

---

If you did want to do it without `CUBE` then you can generate extra rows before pivoting (however, I think `CUBE` will still be more efficient):

```sql
SELECT title AS status,
       "1",
       "2",
       "3",
       "5",
       "1" + "2" + "3" + "5" AS total
FROM   (
  SELECT l.*, t.user_type
  FROM   table_name t
         CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
           SELECT t.status, TO_CHAR(t.status) AS title, 1 AS priority FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
           SELECT NULL,     'SUB_TOTAL',                2 FROM DUAL WHERE t.status IN (2,4,5) UNION ALL
           SELECT NULL,     'TOTAL',                    3 FROM DUAL
         ) l
)
PIVOT ( COUNT(*) FOR user_type IN (1,2,3,5) )
ORDER BY priority, status
```

Which produces the same output.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OBbuPqU2)

Comment: thank you very much, indeed these solution dont seem to be too effecient. but its always worth knowing.

Comment: @userAAb Updated with an alternate solution.